# How should I design my SQL tables?

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently building a desktop application that goes like this: Users create a project, and add questions/answers (each question has only one non-null answer). Each project can have an unlimited amount of questions/answers,and each question/answer can be linked to an unlimited amount of projects.

I created both tables of projects and questions, but I don't know how I should link both. I would have thought of add the project ID to each question, but then the questions could only have been linked to one project.

[image]

Example:

```
Project name: Geography
Project name: History

Question: When did the WW1 end?
Answer: 1918
Linked to: Geography, History, ...
```

The question can be included into both projects, and both projects could have more questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a table to link projects and QAs:

```
 Create table Projects_QAs(ProjectID int not null,QuestionID int not null,
 primary key(ProjectID,QuestionID)
 )
```

You may also create `foreign keys` to link `QuestionID` and `ProjectID` to the `ID`s of the relevant tables.

Also, you may add an `Index` on (`QuestionID`,`ProjectID`) for faster queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question, so I have a pretty general answer.

There are 3 types of database relationships:
-One-to-one
-One-to-many
-many-to-many

you are currently only thinking about a one-to-one relationship, where the unique id in projects links to one specific unique id in questions

you should be thinking in the one-to-many or many-to-many model.

Edit: Like Ormoz said, a third table could be used to fulfil this many-to-many model where each entry of the new table represents a question/project combo as a way to act as a link between projects and questions ex.

If we have general_question (question_id = 1) which fits in both projects project_1 (project_id = 1) and project_2 (project_id = 2) then we would want 2 records in the new table p1_q1 (with project_id  = 1 and question_id = 1) and p2_q1 (with project_id = 2 and question_id = 1) as a way of linking the two projects to the same question.

Comment: I didn't know the many-to-many concept. With a quick research, I found what it meant and it completes the answer given by Ormoz. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help; Database relationships can be a bit tricky while your learning them, but once you start implementing them they become more clear.